# Separation of Variables problem, dye is dropped onto square

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Alright, so this one's pretty long so stay with me here. A dye is dropped onto a square sheet of filter paper and the concentration of the dye is described by the equation u(x,y,t) which has the following relationship:

$$
 u_t = u_{xx} + u_{yy}
$$

You're given the following boundary values:
$$
  u(1,y,t) = u(-1,y,t) = 0
$$
$$
  u_y(x,1,t) = u(x,-1,t) = 0
$$

I tried solving the problem using the method in the textbook, but I got very confused mid-way through. Here's what I did
$$
  u(x,y,t) = X(x)Y(y)T(t)
$$
$$
  X(x)Y(y)T'(t) = X''(x)Y(y)T(t) + X(x)Y''(y)T(t)
$$
Now you divide both sides by XYT.
$$
 \frac{T'}{T} = \frac{X''}{X} + \frac{Y''}{Y}  
$$
I first solved for X so I rearranged the formula to
$$
 \frac{X''}{X} = \frac{T'}{T} - \frac{Y''}{Y}  
$$
The right side depends on T and Y, so you can treat it like a constant.
$$
  X''-KX = 0
$$
I split into three different cases: K>0, K=0 and K<0, and to save you time I found out that the first two cases produces only trivial solutions, so the problem I had was with K<0
$$
  X(x) = c_1 cos(Kx)+c_2 sin(Kx)
$$
Apply boundary conditions:
$$
  u(1,y,t) = X(1)Y(y)T(t) = 0
$$
Because Y and T are not zero for all values of y and t, X(1) must equal zero. I do the same thing with X(-1) and get the following two equations.
$$
  0 = c_1 cosK + c_2 sinK
$$
$$
  0 = c_1 cos(-K) + c_2 sin(-K)
$$
The second can be written to:
$$
  0 = c_1 cos(K) - c_2 sin(K)
$$
And solve, this is where I had trouble. I got both of the two following two equations:
$$
   0 = 2c_2 sin K
$$
$$
   0 = 2c_1 cos K
$$
For the first case, 
$$
  K = - \pi * n
$$
where n is 1,2,3... and c2 is not equal to zero.

For the second case,
$$
  K = \frac{\pi}{2}* (1 - 2n)
$$
where n is 1,2,3... and c1 is not equal to zero. Now that means there are three cases, right? Either c1 is zero and c2 is not, c2 is zero and c1 is not or c1 and c2 are not zero. The last case doesn't work because that means K is both the first case and the second case at the same time and they never overlap. However, the first two cases come up with different solutions, so which one do I use. Is there a way to combine the two cases? Am I making any sense? Is there any logic in the world?

Comment: Your boundary conditions (all$=0$) are not sufficient to determine a unique solution. This is the cause of non consistency.